# Loading or Activating ChartJS on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, chart.js

I have Chart.js set up with a form so that it takes input fields from the form and after clicking Submit/Update button, it generates a donut chart using those numbers from the input fields as data points.

The issue is how can I get the form or Chart.js to run **once** and generate a donut chart with the input fields numbers **when its on the page** (on page load).

The form input fields are already filled with numbers/data via HTML5 Local Storage).

I've tried jQuery .submit(); on page load but nothing happens. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT: I've gone ahead and created a fiddle to re-create the issue.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#submit-btn").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var outputyearly = $('#outputyearly');
        var amount = parseInt($('#amount').val().replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
        var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val(), 10);
        var term = parseFloat($('#term').val(), 10);

        // Some math calculations code

        if (window.onload.myDoughnutChart != null) {
            window.onload.myDoughnutChart.destroy();
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

        window.onload.myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Can we see code examples?

Comment: @Jinjubei added to the original post. Thank you!

Comment: I've trimmed the code basically it takes the values from the inputs in the form, uses those values to draw a donut chart using Chart.js when a visitor hits submit.

I am looking for a way to run the form/Chart.js one time once the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code that draws the chart in a function and call that function on both the `$(document).ready` and `$("#submit-btn").click` event, like this:

```
function drawChart() {
  var outputyearly = $('#outputyearly');
  var amount = parseInt($('#amount').val().replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
  var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val(), 10);
  var term = parseFloat($('#term').val(), 10);

  //Destroy the dougnut chart here, not sure how it's accessible, but it won't work through window.onload

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

  new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: options
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  drawChart();
  $("#submit-btn").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     drawChart();
   });
 });
```

Note that `$(document).ready` already imposes the code inside of it to be executed when the page is done, so putting a `window.onload` inside of it won't make any difference.

Comment: I placed the `window.onload` because that was the only way to get the chart to regenerate and destroy the old one so that it won't keep regenerating on top of it when the visitor changes the values in the form input and hits Submit/Update again. I will try your suggestion. Thank you so much!

Comment: It did not seem to run the Chart.js on page load after wrapping it in a function `drawChart();` and calling it after `$(document).ready(function()` Still getting the same result.

Comment: @foojae please post a JSFiddle with all code required to run it so we (the answerers) can see the results of what we're trying

Comment: will do, let me set that up. Thanks.

Comment: I've gone ahead and created a jsFiddle as requested. I've posted the link here as well as in the original post. Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/foojae/43oy6rn4/

Comment: Your function wrapping worked! There was interference from another jQuery plugin that was causing the issue. Thank you @leroydev !!!